# React: Filtered Search / 'cities' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, search, filter, react-router

I am trying to make a filtered search in react, however it keeps giving me an error: 
'cities' is not defined  no-undef

I have one component: Cities.js

```
import React from "react";
export default class Cities extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    cities: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "http://localhost:5000/cities/all";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    this.setState({ cities: data, loading: false });
    console.log(data);
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      search: ""
    };
  }

  updateSearch(event) {
    this.setState({ search: event.target.value.substr(0, 10) });
  }

  render() {
    // FILTER
    let filteredCities = this.state.cities.filter(city => {
      return (
        cities.city.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !==
        -1
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.search}
          onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}
        />

        {this.state.loading ? (
          <div> loading... </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            {this.state.cities &&
              filteredCities.map(places => (
                <div key={places._id}>
                  {places.city}, {places.country}{" "}
                  <div>
                    <img src={places.url} />
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I started having issues once I added the:
// FILTER
 let filteredCities = this.state.cities.filter(city => {
          return (
            cities.city.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !==
            -1

Comment: I think your condition in filter should be: `city.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The undefined error is caused by your filtering callback using undefined `cities`. You need to use `city` instead.

Example:

```
render() {
    // FILTER
    const filteredCities = this.state.cities.filter(city => {
        return city.city.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLowerCase())
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.search}
          onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}
        />

        {this.state.loading ? (
          <div> loading... </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            {filteredCities &&
              filteredCities.map(places => (
                <div key={places._id}>
                  {places.city}, {places.country}{" "}
                  <div>
                    <img src={places.url} />
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You may also be removing `cities` from your default state in your constructor (which could potentially cause issues). Instead you could remove the defined object from the class, and simply define it in the constructor via `this.state`. Example:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      search: "",
      loading: true,
      cities: []
    };
}
```

Additionally, since you are using an `aync + await` function, it is highly recommended to wrap your awaits in a `try...catch` to handle any potential errors.

Example:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "http://localhost:5000/cities/all";
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ cities: data, loading: false });
        console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Seg, thanks a lot for the tips. 
You definitely did get me a step further, as you solved the error I was getting. Thank you!

Comment: Issue being, now there is a new error:
TypeError: city.toLowerCase is not a function

Allowing me now to go to the Landing page, but not to ./cities

Comment: hmm, what is `city`? is it an object or a string?

Comment: nvm, I see it should be `city.city.toLowerCase()`

Comment: you are a SUPERSTAR! Thanks! 
Im new here, let me know if I can endorse you somehow...